# Rename level 0 columns based on level 1 columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rename

Let's assume a pandas df with the following columns:

df.columns:
(xxx, a, k),
(xxx, b, l),
(xxx, c, m)

I would like to rename the level 0 of this df based on the values of level 1.
For example, what I would like to achieve is to rename the level 0 (xxx) of the second column because of the value of level 1:

df.columns:
(xxx, a, k),
(yyy, b, l) as level 1 = b,
(xxx, c, m)

Any idea?

Comment: Need more clarification can you add the dataframe in a table way and expected result from it and the code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the multiindex columns and check if the column matches level 0 and level 1 pattern and replace it with new level 0 target value

```py
def rename(df, level_0_pat, level_0_tar, level_1_pat):
    columns = [(level_0_tar, ) + col[1:]
               if col[0] == level_0_pat and col[1] == level_1_pat
               else col
               for col in df.columns]
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns, name=df.columns.names)
    return df

df = rename(df, 'xxx', 'yyy', 'b')
```